# lmer Fail to converge

Tags: r, lme4

I am running an experiment testing how moral values (specifically, egalitarianism and communitarianism) influence stock invest decisions.
I have given participants three different information and asked to decide if they were going to invest in the company's stock. The information was

1. Advisor Type: Advice from two financial advisor. Each advisor is coded as -1 and 1.
2. News Type: Good or bad news/action of the firm. Coded as -1 and 1.
3. Company: 12 Different firms.

Participants indicated their likelihood to invest on a 0-100 scale. Which is the variable named Investment.

There's no problem running this model

```
Model <- lmer(Investment ~ Commu + egal + AdvisorType + 
                           AdvisorType:egal + Company + Company:egal+ 
                           NewsType + NewsType:egal+
                           (AdvisorType+NewsType|Participants),
                           data = MM5A, na.action = na.exclude)
```

But when I add company into the slope. I get the following error message.

```
Model1 <-lmer(Investment ~ Commu + egal + AdvisorType + AdvisorType:egal + 
                           Company + Company:egal+ NewsType +      
                           NewsType:egal+
                           (AdvisorType+NewsType+Company|Participants), 
                           data = MM5A, na.action = na.exclude)
```

> Warning message:
> In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
> Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00724121 (tol = 0.002, component 1)

I get the same error messages when I run without `AdvisorType` or `NewsType` in the slope. However, I can run the model with both out (i.e. only `Company` as slope)

If anyone has any idea how to resolve this please let me know.
I have included a screenshot of my datafile [MM5A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvVAU.png) and if you would like any other information please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: What package does function *lmer()* belong to? Couldn't find it in the stat, base or utils packages?

Comment: The lmer function is from the "lme4" package. You also need the "Matrix" package as well to install.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to extend the number of iterations allowed to the optimizer or the type of optimizer. I found [this page](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html) very helpful for such cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will try extending.